# Make data from store app-wide available?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've got a `base`-route encapsulating all other routes in my application.

I'd like to make the categories I retrieve from the store via `this.store.find('category')` available everywhere in my application.

I tried retrieving it in the base-controller with this code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  // retrieve all categories as they are needed in several places
  categories: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('category');
  }
});
```

and creating an alias from child-controllers via:

```
categories: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.base.categories')
```

but it gives this error-message:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed function () {
>           return this.get('store').find('category');
>         }

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a computed property.

```
categories: function() {
  return this.get('store').find('category');
}.property()
```

Controllers are being deprecated in 2.0, so I'd look into using a service architecture instead of a base controller architecture.

Comment: thanks for the information. Where can I read up on the subject, especially how I should handle problems like these right now?